# CMD IF statement with IMAGE Dimmensions

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I need CMD `if` statement script to move files to certain folders depending on image name. In other words, script needs to check image file name: `123456_large.jpg` and move it to folder `LARGE`. But once file is moved to this folder it needs to be renamed to: `123456.jpg` instead of `123456_large.jpg`...

So `if` statement finds `*_LARGE.jpg`, move to `LARGE` folder and rename filename to delete `_LARGE`.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Instead of claiming you did so much research you should share your efforts; otherwise this is a write-code-for-me-for-me question which is off-topic here... Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the files are in one common folder and the large directory also exists in that common folder you could use this.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b *.jpg') DO (
    IF /I "%%~nH"=="large" move "%%~G_%%~H" "large\%%~G%%~xH"
)
```

So essentially what this code does:
Gets a listing of all jpg files in the current folder the batch file is in.
Splits the file name at the first underscore and assigns the first part of the file name to the variable %%G and the rest of the file name to %%H.
Using the FOR variable modifiers, it then checks if the second part of the filename without the extension is equal to large.  If it is, it then moves the file and renames it at the same time, again using the FOR variable modifiers.

If you want to read about the FOR modifiers open up a cmd prompt and type: FOR /?
It is the very last section of the help file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked absolutely perfect! Now a few improvements... Is there a way to do the same thing a previous script, but if file is named: 123456_ALT1_large.jpg (or ALT2, ALT3, ALT4)?